# List of items using count and average in MYSQL Workbench producing too few results

Tags: mysql, count, average

I have a list of book titles that I need to first count more than four copies per title (in alphabetical order), then total the book title and find the average price.  However, my code only produces 1 book, instead of a list.  This is what I need to produce:

```
Title   Count   Average Price    

ABC       6      15.95
DEF       6      21.67
GHI       7      11.47
```

This is what I get:

```
Title   Count   Average Price    

ABC       98      15.95
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
Book_Title AS 'Title',
COUNT(Copy_Num) AS `Count`,
Round(Avg(Copy_Price), 2) AS "Average Price"
FROM BOOK
JOIN COPY USING (Book_Code)
JOIN BRANCH USING (Branch_Num)
HAVING Count(Copy_Num) > 4
ORDER BY Book_Title;
```

What am I missing?  Is it additional code or is something in the wrong order?

Thanks in advance for responding, everything else I tried has produced syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY Book_Title` statement.

```
SELECT 
  Book_Title AS 'Title',
  COUNT(Copy_Num) AS 'Count',
  Round(Avg(Copy_Price), 2) AS 'Average Price'
FROM BOOK
  JOIN COPY USING (Book_Code)
  JOIN BRANCH USING (Branch_Num)
GROUP BY Book_Title
HAVING Count(Copy_Num) > 4
ORDER BY Book_Title;
```